# scipy missing libifport.so.5

Tags: scipy, pip

I am trying to install scipy 0.10.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 using pip.

I have successfully installed numpy:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade numpy
[snip]
Successfully installed numpy
Cleaning up...
```

but when I try scipy I get:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade scipy
  [snip]
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
      from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
ImportError: libifport.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I do have libifport.so.5, but I don't know why the installer isn't finding it.

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  :/opt/intel/composerxe-2011.2.137/compiler/lib/intel64
```

I have also tried to install several other packages in the hope that one of them might help (e.g. libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev, etc)

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you might be mixing gcc-build lapack builds and intel-fortran-built lapack builds?  (I'm guessing based on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I'm quite likely entirely wrong there.)  If that's the case, you'll need to specify the fortran compiler that scipy should use (see the `--fcompiler` option to `setup.py`).  However, you can't mix and match libraries built with gcc's fortran and intel's fortran.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'd like to avoid mixing libraries.  Do you happen to know of a package that would have the library in question?  I tried locate libifport.so.5, but the only hits are from programs that were built with ifort (I'm guessing).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not defined the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for root. To check this:

`$` sudo su

`$`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

You can specify environment variables as follows:

`$` sudo env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/compiler' pip install scipy

Check out this blog post to create an alias to save you typing each time: 
http://final-world-domination.blogspot.ch/2011/02/sudo-doesnt-export-ldlibrarypath.html

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me on Debian 9:
`conda install -c intel -c conda-forge -c pytorch --override-channels intel-fortran-rt`

```
# find / -iname "libifport*"
./opt/conda/lib/libifport.so
./opt/conda/lib/libifport.so.5
./opt/conda/pkgs/intel-fortran-rt-2021.3.0-intel_3350/lib/libifport.so
./opt/conda/pkgs/intel-fortran-rt-2021.3.0-intel_3350/lib/libifport.so.5
```